Passing a function within a pytest parametrize
I am wondering if I can pass a function, instead of an iterable to a fixture via parametrize?
Example, I would want to do something like this.
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def sample_data():
    data = 1
    return data

@pytest.fixture
def fixt(request):
    sample_data = request  # Not sure what the syntax should be here. 
    # Do something with sample_data
    return sample_data


@pytest.mark.parametrize("fixt", sample_data, indirect=True)
def test_indirect(fixt):
    assert fixt == 1

In my actual project, I want to be passing different sample Dataframes to a MagicMock object.
So far I am getting a: TypeError: object of type 'SubRequest' has no len()

since I am checking the length of the dataframe in the actual testcase


This is possible, but there is a couple of errors in your implementation.
First, you use a fixture instead of a function - this won't work, because you cannot access fixtures in parametrize. Second, the parameter is saved in request.param, not in request. And lastly, you need an iterable as the argument value in parametrize.
So, a working version would be:
import pytest

def sample_data1():
    data = 1
    return data

def sample_data2():
    data = 2
    return data

@pytest.fixture
def fixt(request):
    sample_data = request.param()
    # do something with the data
    return sample_data


@pytest.mark.parametrize("fixt, expected", [(sample_data1, 1),
                                            (sample_data2, 2)], indirect=["fixt"])
def test_indirect(fixt, expected):
    assert fixt == expected

I have adapted the answer to have different sample data functions. If you don't need to parametrize the test with different functions, another solution without parametrization may be used instead.

Not sure if I am falling foul of the rules here....but ChatGPT proposed using a factory fixture. As I need to instantiate a new fixt(with different sample data for each test) this appears to solve my problem.
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def sample_data1():
    data = 1
    return data
@pytest.fixture
def sample_data2():
    data = 2
    return data

@pytest.fixture
def fixt_factory():
   def fixt(sample_data):
    sample_data = sample_data
    # Do something with sample_data
    return sample_data
return fixt

def test_indirect(fixt):
    fixt = fixt_factory(sample_data1)  # Alternatively I can pass sample_data2 here
    assert fixt == 1

